# Adding Model to a hasmany relationship wont unpdate

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to add model to a hasmany relationship. In my route I have:

```
App.CourseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('course','-JNPcfHFQC8FNwyt_-Wh');
    }
});
```

and in my controller I have a save action:

```
App.CourseController=Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {

         var _this = this;
         var course = this.get('model');
         _this.get('session').get('user').get("courses").pushObject(course)
         _this.get('session').get('user').save()

    }
  }
});
```

The session property refers a [global sessions object](https://gist.github.com/VictorSigma/3019a2e591917c3e7f3e) that is injected into the controller. This project is using firebase and emberFire data adapter. No errors are being thrown and no data is updated on the firebase backend. I can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoint your code before the `save` call and you'll probably see that `this.get('session').get('user')` has an `isDirty` property of `false`. So the save becomes a no-op. You can try to solve that by calling`this.get('session').get('user').notifyPropertyChange('courses')`.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I am new to ember so could you illuminate me on why this is necessary? I'm using pushobject so shouldn't change the isDirty property?

Comment: It's sort of a long story. The simple answer is that `courses` itself hasn't changed, just its contents...